# What are great modern options for helpers and frameworks for an html5 tablet site's front end?

Tags: javascript, html, architecture, tablet, frontend

I'm trying to ask this question in a non-subjective way. The question is pretty much this:

If you had the chance to write the front end for a high-feature-count, webkit-tablet-targeted web application with rich UI demands that uses web services for all of it's data handling, what frameworks and helper libraries are the best options?

I've tried my best to keep a strong front end stack going, but I wonder now if I'm missing anything really awesome and useful.

I have and want no control over the back end, but I can change anything on the front end that I like. Here's what my stack looks like now:

- Modularization - curl.js
- DOM Abstraction - Zepto
- Capability Detection - Modernizr
- Templating - Mustache
- Code Analysis - JSHint
- Unit Testing - Qunit
- Test Automation - Maven->PhantomJS

And pieces I know of that I haven't decided on yet:

- History Managment - History.js?
- MVC/Data Models - spine.js?
- Module Stitching - cujo/cram?

What do you guys think? Am I missing anything? Am I crazy to not be using coffeescript? Is this how you would do it? I have chance to build the perfect front end architecture on the most modern web technology out there, and I want to nail it.

Comment: I'd suggest checking out backbone.js as an alternative to spine.js for MVC/Data models. Works well in combination with Zepto. It's really a matter of taste but I also prefer underscore.js templating (underscore being a prerequisite of backbone).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this just to close it. I was hoping to get a super-huge list of community-vetted front end frameworks, but I think it's too subjective a topic or too large a list to be useful for SO. Sorry ya'll.